# Slickgrid; handle mouseover/hover events on elements in cell myself

Tags: event-handling, slickgrid

In a very special slickgrid scenario (see https://serenity.is/demo/BasicSamples/DragDropInTreeGrid) I need to handle hover / Mouseover events on the Tree elements (links) myself.

However, Slickgrid is hijacking/disabling my registered hover/mouseover events.

**What I already have tried:**

**(1)**
Using slickgrid's mouseEnter event routine which in normal slickgrids give you back the cell on which the mouseover event has occured.

--> this works basically but for an unknown reason this is very unreliable in my special scenario above (the event always fires but sometimes it comes directly from the `<a href..>` (which is what I want) - but most of the time it comes from a `<div>...` which is useless in my scenario).

(As I could successfully register a contextmenu event on the tree elements and this always works reliably on the elements), I also would like the same principle for the hover/mouseover events).

**(2)**
Prevent the mouseenter events from the tree elements to propagate - like this:

```
this.slickGrid.onMouseEnter.subscribe((e, dd) => {
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

--> This had no effect.

**Question:**
How can I stop slickgrid from hijacking/unregister my registered mouseover/hover events on the tree elements so that I can handle them myself?

Comment: Are you aware that Slickgrid uses a different and custom library for drag and drop? Not sure what flavour of Slickgrid Serenity uses - it may be a different build that has different dependencies. This is probably the first thing to establish.

Comment: check out this: https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/issues/239